# what happening for this line $this->config->get('config_customer_price')

Tags: opencart

I didn't get the idea what really happening here `$this->config->get('config_customer_price')`

```
if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) ||
     !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {

    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
} else {
    $price = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an option in the System / Settings page, under the Option tab, and Account section, which is:

`Login Display Prices: Only show prices when a customer is logged in.`

So, that part of the code is just checking the following:

If this option is set and the customer is logged in, OR if this option is disabled, then: display the price. Otherwise: don't display the price.